# Open Links in App Mode in Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications

Information:

I'm developing Web App in chrome I can make shortcut in desktop to open my app in App Mode through **More tools** >> **add to desktop**.

The problem is when I try to open any Link in new window with hot key **Shift**. It opens in normal mode full features with address bar and tabs bar.

Question Is:

Is there a way to make the links open in new window with the same App Mode in Chrome ?

Regards,